# WPF call method with property

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm not very proficient with WPF. What I want to do is bind to a property from my view and then set that value with something. I've got that part working without trouble, but I have a feeling I'm not properly using the MVVM pattern here. I have my property in the ViewModel, bound to the View however I can't seem to get the Model part working as I intend as the method where the property gets its value from is currently also in the ViewModel.

Here's what I currently have:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private Awesome _model; //this is my model
    private string _score;

    public string Score
    {
        get { return GetScore(); }
        set
        {
            _score = value;
        }
    }

    public string GetScore()
    {
        try
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\somepath"))
            {
                String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
                return line;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("File could not be found! :(");
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine, but everything is in the ViewModel right now. As far as I understand, GetScore() should be in the Model, but then I'm not sure how to set the property with it. What am I missing here?

Comment: You can put `Score` and `GetScore()` into your Model, and only expose a property of your Model in the ViewModel, then in your View, you can bind to `ModelProperty.Score`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GetScore()`-Method should not be in the Model. The model is the data-layer so there are only data-objects with there properties. Methods and other stuff are coordinated by the ViewModel. So you can let your GetScore-Method in your ViewModel or move it to another class and call it from your ViewModel.

By the way: Your property is a little bit weird. becaus in your setter you're setting a backend-field which will never be used again. Are you sure that this is what you want? You should also not always read a file in the getter.

Maybe you want to do something like:

```
public string Score
{
    get { return _score ?? (_score = GetScore()); }
}
```

So you only read the file once and keep the value saved in _score.

Answer (score 1):

Your GetScore() belongs to the ViewModel, as it is the data layer. (Of course you could move it to another class, but it's not wrog from my POV in the ViewModel, see it as an extended getter ;))

But

1. You should make GetScore private, because you have a property for it
2. You should not influence the UI from the ViewModel, so I would
   advise you to not open the MessageBox from the ViewModel.
3. Use `return this.GetScore()`

Comment: What advantage does it have to use `return this.GetScore()` instead of `return GetScore()`?

Comment: This is really a matter of personal taste, because the this-keyword gets removed by the compiler. From my point of view it has the folowing advantages: 1) It is clear that the property/Variable/whatever belongs to the instance and is not a local field or something.
I allways put it like this: Putting this infront of everything reached its goal, when it changed nothing at all: It helps to prevent ambiguosities. (for example having a method-scoped and and instance variable). When you allways use this, you will never have this problem. BUT THIS IS ONLY PERSONAL TASTE

Comment: FWIW: ViewModel is not data-layer. ViewModel is presentation layer. MVVM do not define how and **where** to define your "infrastructure" or "data layer". ViewModel is strictly for presentation logic. Your business logic goes to either your models and domain/business services (rich domain model) or to domain/business services alone (anemic domain model). Infrastructure (i.e. data access layer) is a completely different abstraction (i.e. via repository or cqrs pattern)